# How can I obtain a chosen Model by the where clause from Collection after the query has been proceeded

Tags: php, laravel, search, relationship

After we get the collection, we can search through it by the:

```
$categories->where('name', $name)
```

That's pretty straight forward, but what if we have a multi level category system and We want to find a model by the given name and we know that model exist somewhere, but we are not sure if it's first level or deeper.

I attempt with

```
$categories->where('name', $name)->orHas('children', function() (...))
```

but this can be used only in Builder, not the collection.
So the question is, how to retrieve a Model from Collection of parents and children by the given key and field without queering the database again.

Of course it's Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collection's [`filter`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter) method:

```php
$filtered = $categories->filter(function ($category) use ($name) {
    return $category->name == $name || $category->children->contains('name', $name);
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks - this is what i was looking for! However I'm getting parent Model as result, but it's not a big deal to go to it's relationship and grab a child when we know the name already. Somehow i missed this method. Once again thanks.